# two programs using gpu acceleration

Tags: macos, opencl, gpu, real-time

very noob question here. 
I want to create a program that applies real-time effects to the screen
 (mac os), such as blurring, color shift, etc.. 
My question is, 
If a software, that is already using GPU acceleration, is running (such as Adobe Photoshop) how likely am I to run into problems? 
I guess I'm asking if it's possible for two programmes to access GPU acceleration/OpenCL at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple programs can safely use the same GPU. You may encounter stuttering or other issues if you're doing something intensive, but otherwise it will be fine. If you want to be safe, you can check [CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) to make sure it's OK to use a device, or use [clCreateSubDevices](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubDevices.html) to partition a single OpenCL device into multiple sub-devices that can work independently (just to clarify, this *is not* required, but does give you finer control)

Comment: ty kindly :) 
i guess i need to research what photoshop "takes" in terms of gpu resources, and design the secondary app accordingly

Comment: @Zohar I wouldn't worry about it too much, it will probably be fine. If this answered your question, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so that the question is marked as solved!